# How to add retrieval information to Openai's ChatCompletion.create api call

Tags: openai-api

Openai provides a [tutorial](https://github.com/openai/openai-cookbook/tree/main/apps/web-crawl-q-and-a) on adding information from a web site to a `Completion.create` api call.  However it appears that this call has been superceded by the `ChatCompletion.create` call which provides better control over context. So how do you add retrieved information to a `ChatCompletion.create` call?

In particular for the `Completion.create` api call, you add the relevant web pages to the `prompt field` using what looks like a markup language e.g

```
prompt = f"Answer the question based on the context below, and if the question can't be answered based on the context, say \"I don't know\"\n\nContext: {context}\n\n---\n\nQuestion: {question}\nAnswer:"f"Answer the question based on the context below, and if the question can't be answered based on the context, say \"I don't know\"\n\nContext: {context}\n\n---\n\nQuestion: {question}\nAnswer:"
```

where `context` is text from different web pages separated by `"\n\n###\n\n"`, and `question` is the actual question to be answered.

The `ChatCompletion.create` call does not have a `prompt` field, instead it has a `messages` field and it does not appear to parse the markup. So how do you put such information into the `ChatCompletion.create` call. I have tried using

```
'messages': ['role': 'user', 'content': prompt]
```

but this returns a much shorter answer than using the `Completion.create` api.

Comment: What does "it does not appear to parse the markup" mean? What happens? Do you get an error?

Comment: It does not return an error but gives a much terser response. I have added more information to my question.

Comment: The `Completion.create api` does not accept the `gpt-3.5-turbo` model, so it would seem that you need to use the `ChatCompletion.create` if you want to use the latest models for the functionality described in Openai's tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I found is that the best approach is to treat it like an adult and give it the necessary information to answer the question properly.  So my messages was

```
[
  { 'role': 'user', 'content': prompt },
  { 'role': 'user', 'content': question }
]
```

where `prompt` is

```
"Please the answer the next question based on the context below, and if the question can't be answered based on the context, say \"I don't know\"\n\n.  The question is about my web site, and the context are the sections of the web site that have the embeddings that have the closest cosine distance to the question's embedding. Context: #{context}:"
```

and `question` is the text of the question.  In some cases this can give a briefer response than the `Completion.create` api call, but mostly the answers seem to be better.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the 'system' role to provide context with the relevant web pages:

`{'role': 'system', 'content': prompt}`

[https://arize.com/blog-course/mastering-openai-api-tips-and-tricks/#:~:text=Explanation%20of%20Roles%20in%20Messages,assistant%E2%80%9D%20is%20the%20model's%20response](https://arize.com/blog-course/mastering-openai-api-tips-and-tricks/#:%7E:text=Explanation%20of%20Roles%20in%20Messages,assistant%E2%80%9D%20is%20the%20model%27s%20response).